# Issue while parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

*Hello, I would like to have a list of contacts (full name) from a mysql database, I get an error at the json.* thank you in advance

**ERROR :   json.JSONException: Value DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListContact extends Activity {

    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_contact);

        new downloadTask().execute();

    }





  protected class downloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Contact>>{

    ArrayList<Contact> _myListContact;

    Contact contact;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

         progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ListContact.this, "", " Loading ....");

        }


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Contact> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        this._myListContact  = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        String resultat = null ;

        InputStream is = null ;


        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost requete = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/conta.php");
            HttpResponse reponse = httpclient.execute(requete);
            HttpEntity entity = reponse.getEntity();


            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e){

                    Log.e("erreur log" , "erreur lors  connextion htpp" +e.toString());

                } try {

            BufferedReader reader = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is) , 8);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ){

               builder.append(line + "/n");


           } is.close();

           resultat = builder.toString();


        } catch (Exception e){

            Log.e("erreur log" , "erreur lors du parsing " +e.toString());

        }

        try {

            JSONArray _jArray = new JSONArray(resultat.toString());

            for (int i = 0 ; i<_jArray.length(); i++) {

                 contact = new Contact();

                contact.setFull_name(_jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("full_name").toString());

                _myListContact.add(contact);


            } 



        } catch (Exception e){

            Log.e("erreur log" , "erreur lors du parsing json" +e.toString());

        }


        return _myListContact;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> _myListContact) {

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listcontact);
        AdapterContact adapter = new AdapterContact(ListContact.this, _myListContact);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
       progressDialog.dismiss();



    }



}


}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your JSON as well as the code where you are parsing it?

Comment: a simple [{"full_name":"fernando torres"},{"full_name":"tito wassim"}]

Answer (score 0):

I got this error before, Your are not getting JSON from your http request but HTML.

In my case it was a `page not found (404)`

Which was a HTML page where the first line is your doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`)

You have to make sure the URL is correct

```
 HttpPost requete = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/conta.php");
```

Comment: When I test with localhost / conta.php, I see my normal json data, so the script :/ and right, and just view the link that is no error http

Comment: OKay, then add this `header('Content-type: application/json');` at the very top of your php script

Comment: I think it a problem with the wamp localhost when I test it works but when I 192.168.1.2/conta.php address but there is nothing that bug (temp load

Comment: @user2976922 you running on a device or simulator? check this http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses